# Block Scraping of my Website from Others | WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Is their any way to block Scraping of content of my website via some refer protection.

I blocked all bots except google and some known via cloudflare. And disabled the rss.

However still other website easily scraping content in just 1 minute of publishing my content.  I tried to find sol. for this but couldn't. They even scrape each and every html, css, javascript which I am running.

I am thinking if it possible to load this `<?php the_content(); ?>` only when my domain matches something.

If anyone knows please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the scrapper always uses the same IP address, you could block it.

Comment: You can use proxys or auto renew ip from your isp. this will not work. and what if people are behind a router with the same ip?

Comment: @Oliver I tried updating some very old posts and enabled Cloudflare captcha and check all logs but couldn't find anything suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stop someone to download your public client side code on a public side.

Every page that i call up in the browser is already on my computer cache.

You can parse code even with a browser, create your own add-on without using wget, curl, etc..

So it's impossible to hide, even if you try with some js hacks.

You can only hide your server-side code.

Every operation on the server-side is hidden(on a normal way without bugs or something else) and the result you send to the client is public.

You can try doing thinks harder like try to encrypt your code with javascript or hide or what else.., or click this to load that with asynchronous javascript
but on the end again you can't stop someone download your content.

You have to try understand how a browser and a protocol like http works. If you call a site you execute the client side code on your machine.

"What You See Is What You Get"

There is one big rule if you work with transactions like post, get, etc..

**"NEVER TRUST THE DATA YOU RECEIVE"**

That's why we try to use cookies, sessions, etc, because you never know who is on the other side.

Comment: I thought that something can be possible via JavaScript like load content only when website URL matched otherwise some some other texts.

Comment: Client side code can always be copied, because the browser has to download it to run it.  If you include IP or domain checks in the script someone can still edit those out from the downloaded copy of the code.  They can even write scripts to modify your code automatically so it runs on their own server.

Comment: Any data sent to the client can usually be copied too, though you can try to stop this in some cases like video streams where the browser and operating system can try to enforce digital rights management (DRM) used by someone like Netflix.

Comment: Just like @DaveS says, they can try to stop in the case of streaming but with the right software, i can live record the stream just in time.

Comment: Let's call that a hack, i.e. finding a solution to a problem like how can i downloading content, stream, images etc.. the question that always arises is how long do I need to find a solution and is it worth the effort for me.